# regex cant match string with start and end

Tags: regex

so I've never had this problem before, but now I can't figure out how to deal with it,
heres my example:
so I have a simple string: `"1"` and a simple regex: `^[0-9]&`
IT DOES NOT MATCH! it will match fine without the start and end characters, but I need them (for the larger scale problem) anyone have any idea why?
thanks,
Nico

Comment: Why the `&` in your regex? Also are the `"` part of your String?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`&` is not the end of string anchor for regular expressions.  It's typically `$`.  Use `^[0-9]$`.  This allows a string made of *one* numeric character.

Comment: I know it's only one, it was meant as a simple example, It was just a dumb typo, thanks:)

Answer (score -1):

`^[0-9]*$`one or more numbers
`^[0-9]*` one number only

edit: oops

Comment: isn't `[^0-9]` one character that's NOT a number? Isn't `^[0-9]*` zero or more numbers beginning at the start of the test case?

Comment: `*` is a quantifier meaning "zero or more." `^[0-9]*` will match zero or more characters in the set `0123456789` starting at the beginning of the test case.